# How to find occurrences of a string in string in C++?

Tags: c++

How to find occurrences of a string in string in C++?

Here is the Scenario.

```
string base_string = "BF;1;2;3;FF;10;20;30;BF;11;;22;33;FF;100;200;300;BF;110;;220;330;FF;1000;2000;3000";
string to_find_occurances_of = "BF";
```

Comment: @BjörnPollex Removed the tag #c-strings

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
int occurrences = 0;
string::size_type start = 0;

while ((start = base_string.find(to_find_occurrences_of, start)) != string::npos) {
    ++occurrences;
    start += to_find_occurrences_of.length(); // see the note
}
```

`string::find` takes a string to look for in the invoking object and (in this overload) a character position at which to start looking, and returns the position of the occurrence of the string, or `string::npos` if the string is not found.

The variable `start` starts at 0 (the first character) and in the condition of the loop, you use `start` to tell `find` where to start looking, then assign the return value of `find` to `start`. Increment the occurrence count; now that `start` holds the position of the string, you can skip `to_find_occurrences_of.length()`<sup>1</sup> characters ahead and start looking again.

---

<sup>1</sup> drhirsch makes the point that if `to_find_occurrences_of` contains a repeated sequence of characters, doing `start += to_find_occurrences_of.length()` may skip some occurrences. For instance, if `base_string` was `"ffff"` and `to_find_occurrences_of` was `"ff"`, then only 2 occurrences would be counted if you add `to_find_occurrences_of.length()` to `start`. If you want to avoid that, add 1 instead of `to_find_occurrences_of.length()` to `start`, and in that example, 3 occurrences would be counted instead of just 2.

Comment: You will skip some "occurances" if _to_find_occurances_of_ consists of repeated characters or sequences.

Comment: @DreamCodeer forgive me if you already know this, but if this answer answered your question, please mark it as answered by clicking the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie .. Thanks again.. Marked as answered.

Comment: Great! What must I do to make it works, no matter small or capital letters?

Answer (score 2):

Here the code to find string occurance in string with user defined Find function

```
int Find(char OrgStr[], char szFind[]);

void main(){
   int iCount = Find("babbabaab ab", "ab");
   //cout<<"No of 'abe' : " << iCount <<endl;

}

int Find(char orgStr[], char findStr[]){    
    int i,j,k,l,szLen,orgLen;
    char temp[] = " ";

    orgLen = strlen(orgStr);
    szLen = strlen(findStr); 

    k= 0;
    i = 0;
    l = 0;

    while( l < orgLen )
    {
        i = (orgLen - ( orgLen - l));
        for( j = 0; j < szLen; j++)
        {
            temp[j] = orgStr[i];            
            i++;
        }
        temp[j] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(temp,findStr) == 0)
        {
            k++;
        }
        strcpy(temp,"");
        l++;
    }
    cout<<"No of 'ab' : " << k <<endl;
    return k;
    //strcpy(temp,"");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Boost C++ library](https://www.boost.org/) in this case. Here is an example of string matching:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using StringRange = boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>;

int main()
{
    std::string base_string = "BF;1;2;3;FF;10;20;30;BF;11;;22;33;FF;100;200;300;BF;110;;220;330;FF;1000;2000;3000";
    std::string to_find_occurances_of = "BF";

    std::vector<StringRange> matches;
    boost::find_all(matches, base_string, to_find_occurances_of);
    for (auto match : matches) {
        std::cout << "Found [" << to_find_occurances_of << "] at index " << match.begin() - base_string.begin() << ".\n";
    }
}
```

This code prints:

```
Found [BF] at index 0.
Found [BF] at index 21.
Found [BF] at index 49.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
      string str("BF;1;2;3;FF;10;20;30;BF;11;;22;33;FF;100;200;300;BF;110;;220;330;FF;1000;2000;3000");
      string str2 ("BF");
      size_t found;

      // different member versions of find in the same order as above:
      found=str.find(str2);
//print

            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have used the first one.

Comment: What is size_t here?